# Read XML as String from Input Stream continuously

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read XML data from a continuous stream, I need to store each XML in a list of strings. I need the raw XML data simply as string data and not DOM or SAX or any kind of serialization.
I'm currently reading from an InputStream into a Scanner and using a delimeter, but I need to account for a scenario where the XML header is not present.

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?><root></root>"
```

OR

```
String xml = "<root></root>
```

my current implementation is

```
try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
    try (InputStream in = socket.getInputStream()) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        scanner.useDelimiter("<\\?xml.*?\\?>");  //Stop stream read when XMl tag is found
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write a regex that account for either the xml header or the first node? (The first node is always the same)

I've attempted to use a XMLStreamReader but as far as I can figure out it only pull parses the data by traversing through it. That's fine, but I ultimately need the entire XML as a String each time.

EDIT: For clarification there's only one "root" node per XML, the header my be there and it may not. so some scenarios.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<root>
</root>
<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<root>
</root>
<root>
</root>
```

I want to handle all 3 of these xmls as strings

Comment: when you say the first node is always the same, you mean the `<root>` tag?  so that `"<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?><root>pop</root><root>pap</root>"` should give you  list with 2 strings, right?

Comment: Yeah, the root level node is always <root></root>. And there's only one so it's more like     <?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?><root>pop</root><?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?><root>pap</root>"

Comment: and the <xml> tag? can there be several ones in the stream? Could you give a complete example of a stream and the expected list of strings?

Comment: Yes, but some xml's may have it and some might not. Which im having trouble handling a regex that can catch either scenario

Comment: You should never use regex on an xml.  There is always much better approaches.  If you need to remove the ident lines you can read file with streamreader and filter the lines before using xmlreader to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your xml strings are similar in one way, they all end with a `</root>` tag, so you might simply want to read char by char and cut when you encounter the `</root>` tag.

Here is an example using your example string.

```
String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" +
        "<root>" +
        "</root>" +
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" +
        "<root>" +
        "</root>" +
        "<root>" +
        "</root>";

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());

int c;
StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
    xmlString.append((char)c);
    // When you get a closing tag, check if it is </root>
    if( (char)c == '>' && xmlString.toString().endsWith(("</root>")) ) {
        list.add(xmlString.toString());
        xmlString = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
in.close();

list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This outputs 3 Strings

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><root></root>
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><root></root>
<root></root>
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have multiple nodes at the root level which is referred as "Not Well Formed".  So you have to use XmlReader with the settings set to "Fragmented".  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "root")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("root");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement root = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of people who do not like fragmented xml, but they have very useful purpose.  You can use them in log files where you need to append data to the end of a file and easily be able to parse the log files later.  You should never have the xml ident line appear more than once which appears what may be happening in this case.